# VGA and DVI, set default kernel console to one

Tags: linux, kernel, video, radeon

this seems like a very basic question, but after searching the web for 2 hours I couldn't find any real help on the subject and it's driving me nuts.

It's brutally simple: I have a radeon 4670 video card (rv770xt), use Arch Linux' repo kernel and have monitors on VGA and DVI. KMS is enabled and doing fine.

The VGA monitor has a smaller resolution than the DVI monitor and by default the screen is mirrored to both with the VGA monitor's resolution.
Now I don't want to use the VGA monitor at all for the kernel framebuffer/console and want the kernel to use the (bigger) DVI monitor.

Note: This is not about X.org dual-head, it's about the kernel framebuffer/console.

Now here's the question: Are there kernel parameters to specify a default output for my framebuffer and if so, which?

The best way to do that I have found so far seems to use con2fb on startup to move all the VTs to the 2nd monitor, but I don't even know if the radeon driver creates 2 fbs and it would only be a workaround anyways.

**Edit1:** I checked, the driver just creates fb0, so `con2fb` is a no-go

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but could you elaborate on the udev rule?

Comment: Alright, that works :D It doesn't disable mirroring to the VGA output, but I can figure that out from here. Could you turn this into an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `udev` rule and [fbset](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fbset) to force the framebuffer resolution on both displays, which may go some way to achieving what you are after.

The `udev` rule would be along the lines of `/etc/udev/rules.d/81-framebuffer-hack.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="card0-DVI", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ATTR{dpms}=="On", ATTR{enabled}=="enabled", ATTR{status}=="connected", RUN+="/usr/sbin/fbset -g 1920 1080 1920 1080 32"
```

You can read up on the specifics on `udev` rules on the [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) page.